# How do i link a .ejs file to another .ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to link my `cart.ejs` file to my `index.ejs` file but every time i open the server and click on cart i get cannot get/cart

tried changing the link `href` on my `index.ejs` file to be like
`<li><a href="cart">Cart</a></li>` but still not able to link and open cart via the nav bar on my `index.ejs` file

here is how i have set my views directory:
and here is how i've set the views directory: // Set the views directory correctly
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/pages'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(session({
secret: 'secret',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
}));

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't link to EJS files per se.

You write some code which creates a web server ([Express JS](https://expressjs.com/) is a popular library for this) which, for certain URLS, reads and executes an EJS file to generate a response.

You then link to the URLs.

So:

1. Make sure that `cart.ejs` *has* a URL
2. Make sure you know what that URL is supposed to be
3. Look at your browser's address bar and see what absolute URL your link is resolving to

That should reveal what corrections you need.

Comment: yes, i  have an index.js, i had a route to my cart.ejs and had managed to get it working in that when i click on cart on my nav bar it opened the cart, but after adding a route to open my checkout page, the whole server stopped working, it starts but cannot display, based on my knowledge, you have not rendered the index.ejs file in the same route as checkout. i had rendered the index.ejs file in the / route, which is the root route. The /checkout route is a subroute of the / route, which means that it is nested within the / route. but even after omiting the checkout route, still cannot open.

Comment: i have provided the code that shows how i set up my views directory. any other particular code kindly ask for it so that i can paste it.

Comment: actually my main problem now is that, i get this error: Error: Failed to lookup view "pages/index" in views directory "C:\Users\Trap\Desktop\project\Dunga Beach Resort\views\pages" even though the index file is in that directory.